# Android Paging 3 leading to duplicate rows

Tags: android, kotlin, paging, android-paging, android-paging-3

I was trying out the Paging 3.0.1 version. The API calls are happening right when I printed the log. But the data shown is duplicate. Could someone tell me where I went wrong?

Page data source class

```
class MyPageDataSource(private val api: RetrofitInstance) :
PagingSource<Int, APIDataResponse>() {

override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, APIDataResponse> {
    return try {
        val nextPageNumber = params.key ?: FIRST_PAGE_NUMBER
        val response = api.getData(nextPageNumber, PAGE_SIZE)
        LoadResult.Page(
            data = response.APIS!!,
            prevKey = if (nextPageNumber > FIRST_PAGE_NUMBER) nextPageNumber - 1 else null,
            nextKey = if (nextPageNumber * PAGE_SIZE < response.total!!) nextPageNumber + 1 else null
        )
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        LoadResult.Error(e)
    }
}

override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, APIDataResponse>): Int? {
    return state.anchorPosition
}

companion object {
    const val FIRST_PAGE_NUMBER = 1
    const val PAGE_SIZE = 20
}
}
```

Adapter:

```
class MyListingAdapter() : PagingDataAdapter<APIDataResponse, MyListingAdapter.MyViewHolder>(MyComparator) {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    return MyViewHolder(
        FragmentItemBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent,
            false
        )
    )
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(item = getItem(position))
}

inner class MyViewHolder(binding: FragmentItemBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    private val title: TextView = binding.title

    fun bind(item: APIDataResponse?) {
        if(item != null) {
            title.text = item.title
        }
    }
}

object MyComparator : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<APIDataResponse>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(
        oldItem: APIDataResponse,
        newItem: APIDataResponse
    ): Boolean {
        return oldItem.id == newItem.id
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(
        oldItem: APIDataResponse,
        newItem: APIDataResponse
    ): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}
}
```

View Model:

```
class PagingViewModel : ViewModel() {

fun getData() : Flow<PagingData<APIDataResponse>> {
    return Pager(
        PagingConfig(
            pageSize = 20,
            enablePlaceholders = false,
            maxSize = 40,
            initialLoadSize = 20,
            prefetchDistance = 10
        )
    ) {
        MyPageDataSource(RetrofitInstance())
    }.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
}
}
```

Recycler view setting up in the fragment:

```
val myAdapter = MyListingAdapter(myActivity)

    //Setup the recyclerview
    binding.myList.apply {
        layoutManager = when {
            columnCount <= 1 -> LinearLayoutManager(context)
            else -> GridLayoutManager(context, columnCount)
        }
        myAdapter.stateRestorationPolicy = RecyclerView.Adapter.StateRestorationPolicy.PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY
        val decoration =
            DividerItemDecoration(myActivity, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL)
        addItemDecoration(decoration)
        setHasFixedSize(true)
        adapter = myAdapter
    }
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewModel.getData().distinctUntilChanged().collectLatest { pagedData ->
            myAdapter.submitData(pagedData)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi can you explain what your trying to do in the nextKey ? Because thats used to check if we need to load more pages , the implementation i have done there is 
nextKey = if (response.isEmpty()) null else position + 1, is it something to do with how your api works ?

Comment: Each page contains 20 results which is the PAGE_SIZE. nextPageNumber * PAGE_SIZE will return the number of results loaded. I have total field returned from my API. So, I am checking the multiplied value with the total.

Comment: is your `APIDataResponse` a "data class" ? looks to me that the duplicate is happening in the `DiffUtil.ItemCallback`

Comment: @A.David yes its a data class

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
It solved by setting the correct `pageSize`.

This problem can also happen by setting the wrong `maxSize`, `initialLoadSize` or other attributes.

Comment: What is a correct `pageSize`? can u explain??

Comment: @ankuranurag2 Correct `pageSize` means it must be the same as number of items coming from api.

Answer (score 0):

You have set setHasFixedSize(true) it means data won't change because of a change in the adapter content. For example, the RecyclerView size can change because of a size change on its parent. Maybe that's why you are getting the same records. try to remove it and then check it works or not.